Can Xerox Workflow Scanning templates achieve certain document scanning goals in our office?
My office recently replaced our old Canon imageFORMULA scanners with Xerox AltaLink copiers. However, my older colleagues have struggled to adjust to the new technology. The Canon scanners were paired with desktop software that used pre-set scanning profiles, making it easy to digitize various document types. Digitizing paper documents is a daily task in our office and a significant function of our department.
The AltaLinks do not seem to have the ability to save "Scan To" settings as pre-set profiles, requiring manual configuration for each document. This process is too time-consuming for our busy staff. However, I have read about the Workflow Scanning feature available on the AltaLinks and the potential use of templates. Unfortunately, our company has not set up this tool yet.
Would this feature, along with custom templates, allow our office to regain some of the simplicity we had with the Canon scanners? I would need to instruct our IT department on its possible use, but the documentation is too sparse to determine if this is the solution we need.
Any guidance will be appreciated on the intended use cases of Workflow Scanning and whether multiple templates can be setup for the same network folder destination.  If there are alternative Xerox apps that can achieve my goals, I would be happy to hear about them from you. Thank you!
I have identified three groups of "Scan To" app settings that can successfully digitize most of the documents our office encounters, but our staff struggles to memorize which combination of settings is appropriate for each document or entirely ignores the advice in favor of simply "getting the job done" to the detriment of our record quality.  I don't see any feature in the AltaLinks that allows these groups of settings to be saved and retrieved in the Scan To utility, and Workflow Scanning has not been setup by our IT Dept.

Yes! Workflow scanning is your solution. You can set up 100's of scanning templates through workflow scanning. You can even choose different settings for each template, such as Dpi, naming, darken/lightening, etc.
If you only have a few locations, you can even set them up as 1 touch apps. Which will appear as an ap icon on the screen, you can name the icon and set a different icon picture/color for each app. At one time you could even upload a photo as the app icon.
It's hard switching to a different vendor. I have been in the copier business for a long time, and Xerox copiers are the easiest to work with. It's different, but better.
